# Is it possible to autoincrement any number in Laravel Migration?

Tags: php, laravel, database

Is it possible to auto-increment any number other than `id` when doing laravel migration?
I want to auto auto-increment increment `unique_id` on my migration and not default ID, how do I do it?

```
       Schema::create('lims_codes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->increments('unique_id')->startingValue(000001);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Comment: How would `id` work if it's not autoincremented? Why can't you use that as the unique id instead? If you simply want to name your id field `unique_id`, then you can simply pass that name to the `id()` method: `$table->id('unique_id')`

Comment: @M.Eriksson Thanks for the reply, I want to id to increment, as usual, let's say *1,2,3* and `unique_id` also to be incremented starting from *000001* but from different columns. Is it possible?

Comment: `000001` isn't a valid integer though (integers don't start with `0`.) To make that a valid number, it would be `1`. Since you already have an autoincrement field (your `id` field), I don't see the point of adding an extra. Just use the `id` field and [pad it](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) with zeros (however, it will then be a string, not a number).

Comment: @M.Eriksson it is valid though, see zerofill